# Writing a MATLAB script that implements the trapezoidal formula

Tags: matlab

I am aware that there is a trapz function in MATLAB but I have been set the task of creating a script that implements the trapezoidal formula for numerical integration.

Here is my attempt, unfortunately it is not working and help would be greatly appreciated:

> % This program computes the integral of a function using the Trapezoid formula. If [a,b] is the interval of integration, then we introduce the partition a = x_0 < x_1 < x_2 <... < x_n =b
>
> n = 10000;  % Number of subintervals in [a,b].
>
> a = 0;    % Lower limit of integration.
>
> b = 5;     % Upper limit of integration.
>
> del = (b-a)/n; % Length of each subinterval.
>
> f = @    % The function I want to integrate
>
> x = a:del:b;                    % The vector of the partition of [a,b]
>
> xm = (a + del/2):del:(b -del/2);   % The vector of the midpoints of the partition
>
> y = 0.5*(f(a)+f(b)) + f(xm(1:n-1));
>
> mp = del*sum(y) %  These last two lines implement the formula

Comment: You should explain what is exactly your problem here, does Matlab give you an error message ? If it does, what is the message ? It seems to me that $y$ is the vector [(f(a)+f(b))/2+f(x_1),(f(a)+f(b))/2+f(x_2),...,(f(a)+f(b))/2+f(x_{n-1})], no?

Answer (score 1):

I think in your codes the line

```
xm = (a + del/2):del:(b -del/2);
```

is redundant and in line

```
y = 0.5*(f(a)+f(b)) + f(xm(1:n-1));
```

`f(a)` and `f(b)` are scalars and `f(xm(1:n-1)` is a vector so you can not sum a scalar with a vector. So the codes should be as follows:

```
n = 100; % Number of subintervals in [a,b].

a = 0; % Lower limit of integration.

b = 5; % Upper limit of integration.

del = (b-a)/n; % Length of each subinterval.

f = @% The function I want to integrate

x = a:del:b; % The vector of the partition of [a,b]


y = 0.5*([f(a) 2*f(x(2:end-1)) f(b) ]);

mp = del*sum(y) % These last two lines implement the formula
```

Or instead of the last two lines(y and mp) use the following line

```
INT=del*sum(f(x(1:end-1))+f(x(2:end)))/2
```